# Windows - can't find package Expect while executing "package require Expect"

Tags: tcl, expect

I have installed AcctiveState Expect for windows with version 8.6 in my laptop, the following is the files.

```
Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is 3401-82FB Directory of C:\ActiveTcl\bin2021-03-15  05:13 PM    <DIR>          .
2021-03-15  05:13 PM    <DIR>          ..
2015-04-24  07:15 PM            21,874 bitmap-editor.tcl
2019-03-07  03:22 PM               449 critcl
2019-03-07  03:22 PM               449 critcl.tcl
2014-12-03  02:34 PM             1,193 diagram-viewer.tcl
2016-02-04  01:02 AM               837 dtplite.tcl
2016-02-04  01:02 AM             7,234 nns.tcl
2016-02-04  01:02 AM             3,373 nnsd.tcl
2016-02-04  01:02 AM             4,485 nnslog.tcl
2016-02-04  01:02 AM             4,168 pt.tcl
2019-03-07  03:07 PM         1,715,712 tcl86t.dll
2016-02-04  01:02 AM            13,695 tcldocstrip.tcl
2019-03-07  03:07 PM            69,392 tclsh.exe
2019-03-07  03:07 PM            69,392 tclsh86t.exe
2019-03-07  03:07 PM            69,392 tclsht.exe
2019-03-07  03:09 PM         1,470,464 tk86t.dll
2019-03-07  03:22 PM           198,216 tkcon.tcl
2019-03-07  03:09 PM            69,904 wish.exe
2019-03-07  03:09 PM            69,904 wish86t.exe
2019-03-07  03:09 PM            69,904 wisht.exe
```

Then I can run command on windows terminal successfully (it is a dos-like terminal).

```
tclsh
%
```

But when I run tclsh command in my git-bash terminal, it hangs. It seems it doesn't work well in git-bash terminal.

Then I try to run the following scripts named generate-client-cert-for-windows.sh, it failed.

```
#!/bin/sh
# \
exec tclsh "$0" ${1+"$@"}
package require Expect

set timeout -1

spawn openssl pkcs12 -export -in client-ca/user.crt -inkey client-ca/user.key -out client-ca/testkeystore.p12
expect "Enter Export Password:" {send "$env(TRUSTSTORE_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD)\n"}
expect "Verifying - Enter Export Password:" {send "$env(TRUSTSTORE_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD)\n"}
expect eof
```

The above script complains the following errors, it seems not to find Expect, what do I miss or What's wrong for this scripts?

```
can't find package Expect
    while executing
"package require Expect"
    (file "./generate-client-cert-for-windows.sh" line 4)
```

Comment: Looks like the Tcl runtime thinks that the expect package isn't installed.

Comment: I think so. How to install package Expect? I didn't see any documents describe install Expect package. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm on totally the wrong platform to check; it could be something trivial or it could be complicated. What directories are next to that `bin` directory?